# dos switch en visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

puedo hacer dos switch en un mismo método en visual C#? intento hacerlo y en el segundo switch me sale un aviso de error que dice código inalcanzable. gracias por la ayuda.

```
private bool CalcularLibro() {
  switch (TipoPasta.ToUpper()) { 
    case "LUJO": 
                 ValorPasta = 10000; 
                 return true; 
    case "NORMAL":
                 ValorPasta = 5000;
                 return true; 
    default: 
            Error = "No definió el tipo de pasta";
            return false; 
} 

  switch (TipoPpel.ToUpper()) { } 
}
```

Comment: Mostra tu codigo. El problema no son los switchs, es que tu codigo es realmente inalcanzable.

Comment: y esto es java o c#?? por favor, utiliza las etiquetas que corresponde. Lee por favor [ask]

Comment: es C# y en ese método sólo tengo un switch, quiero hacer otro pero me sale ese error y si hago un condicional o cualquier otra cosa no sale el error

Comment: private bool CalcularLibro()
        {
            switch (TipoPasta.ToUpper())
            {
                case "LUJO":
                    ValorPasta = 10000;
                    return true;

                case "NORMAL":
                    ValorPasta = 5000;
                    return true;

                default:
                    Error = "No definió el tipo de pasta";
                return false;
            }
            

            switch (TipoPpel.ToUpper())
            {


            }
        }

Comment: el codigo debe ir en la pregunta. Por favor editala usando el boton [edit]. y borra las etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta. y explica que queres que haga tu metodo

Comment: Los 'return' hacen que salgas de la función "CalcularLibro", bórralos y alcanzarás el segundo switch

Answer (score 7):

Tu código no puede llegar a ejecutar el segundo switch, es imposible y te explico la razón.
Al definir tu método CalcularLibro, indicas que va a devolver un booleano, hasta ahí bien, el problema viene ahora.

Al hacer el primer switch, le has indicado que en cualquiera de los 3 casos que cubre, devuelva true o false, con lo cual al devolver un valor ya no puede continuar, es lógico.

Siempre que pase por un return true o false va a acabar la ejecución de tu método porque ya devuelve lo que tiene que devolver así que da por finalizada su ejecución.

Para evitar esto, no utilices return dentro del switch (a menos que lo necesites), tu código puede quedar algo así sin saber ese segundo switch lo que hace:

```
private bool CalcularLibro() {

  bool esPasta = false;   //Definimos un bool y será este el que devolvamos

  switch (TipoPasta.ToUpper()) { 
    case "LUJO": 
             ValorPasta = 10000; 
             esPasta = true;    //Pasamos nuestra variable a true
             break;             //Ponemos break para salir del switch
    case "NORMAL":
             ValorPasta = 5000;
             esPasta = true;    //Pasamos nuestra variable a true
             break;             //Ponemos break para salir del switch
    default: 
             Error = "No definió el tipo de pasta";
             esPasta = false;   //No ponemos break porque es la última opción del switch
  } 

  switch (TipoPpel.ToUpper()) { }   //Hacemos lo que tengamos que hacer aquí

  return esPasta;  //Devolvemos el bool con el resultado que hayamos obtenido
}
```